# Performance issue for join on the same tables multiple times

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

I am facing a performance issue for the below query where the same table is self joined multiple times. How can i avoid multiple joins on same table?

```
INSERT INTO "TEMP"."TABLE2"
SELECT
T1."PRODUCT_SNO"
,T2."PRODUCT_SNO"
,T3."PRODUCT_SNO"
,T4."PRODUCT_SNO"
,((COUNT(DISTINCT T1."ACCESS_METHOD_ID")(FLOAT)) / 
   (MAX(T5.GROUP_NUM(FLOAT))))
FROM
"TEMP"."TABLE1" T1
,"TEMP"."TABLE1" T2
,"TEMP"."TABLE1" T3
,"TEMP"."TABLE1" T4
,"TEMP"."_TWM_GROUP_COUNT" T5
WHERE
      T1."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T2."ACCESS_METHOD_ID"
  AND T2."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T3."ACCESS_METHOD_ID"
  AND T3."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T4."ACCESS_METHOD_ID"
  AND T1."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" < T2."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
  AND T2."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" < T3."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
  AND T3."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" < T4."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

This is taking 3 hrs to complete. Below is the explain for it:

```
1) First, we lock a distinct TEMP."pseudo table" for write on a
     RowHash to prevent global deadlock for
     TEMP.TABLE2. 
  2) Next, we lock a distinct TEMP."pseudo table" for read on a
     RowHash to prevent global deadlock for TEMP.T5. 
  3) We lock TEMP.TABLE2 for write, we lock
     TEMP.TABLE1 for access, and we lock TEMP.T5 for read. 
  4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from TEMP.T5 by way of an
     all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 4 (all_amps),
     which is duplicated on all AMPs.  The size of Spool 4 is estimated
     with high confidence to be 48 rows (816 bytes).  The estimated
     time for this step is 0.01 seconds. 
  5) We execute the following steps in parallel. 
       1) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of
          an all-rows scan, which is joined to TEMP.T4 by way of an
          all-rows scan with no residual conditions.  Spool 4 and
          TEMP.T4 are joined using a product join, with a join
          condition of ("(1=1)").  The result goes into Spool 5
          (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  Then we do a
          SORT to order Spool 5 by the hash code of (
          TEMP.T4.ACCESS_METHOD_ID).  The size of Spool 5 is
          estimated with high confidence to be 8,051,801 rows (
          233,502,229 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1.77
          seconds. 
       2) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from TEMP.T2 by way of a
          RowHash match scan with no residual conditions, which is
          joined to TEMP.T1 by way of a RowHash match scan with no
          residual conditions.  TEMP.T2 and TEMP.T1 are joined
          using a merge join, with a join condition of (
          "(TEMP.T1.ACCESS_METHOD_ID = TEMP.T2.ACCESS_METHOD_ID)
          AND (TEMP.T1.SUBSCRIPTION_DATE <
          TEMP.T2.SUBSCRIPTION_DATE)").  The result goes into Spool
          6 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size
          of Spool 6 is estimated with low confidence to be 36,764,681
          rows (1,213,234,473 bytes).  The estimated time for this step
          is 4.12 seconds. 
  6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 5 (Last Use) by way of a
     RowHash match scan, which is joined to TEMP.T3 by way of a
     RowHash match scan with no residual conditions.  Spool 5 and
     TEMP.T3 are joined using a merge join, with a join condition
     of ("(TEMP.T3.SUBSCRIPTION_DATE < SUBSCRIPTION_DATE) AND
     (TEMP.T3.ACCESS_METHOD_ID = ACCESS_METHOD_ID)").  The result
     goes into Spool 7 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. 
     The size of Spool 7 is estimated with low confidence to be
     36,764,681 rows (1,360,293,197 bytes).  The estimated time for
     this step is 4.14 seconds. 
  7) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of a
     RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 7 (Last Use) by way
     of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 6 and Spool 7 are joined using a
     merge join, with a join condition of ("(SUBSCRIPTION_DATE <
     SUBSCRIPTION_DATE) AND ((ACCESS_METHOD_ID = ACCESS_METHOD_ID) AND
     ((ACCESS_METHOD_ID = ACCESS_METHOD_ID) AND ((ACCESS_METHOD_ID =
     ACCESS_METHOD_ID) AND (ACCESS_METHOD_ID = ACCESS_METHOD_ID ))))"). 
     The result goes into Spool 3 (all_amps), which is built locally on
     the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be cached in memory. 
     The size of Spool 3 is estimated with low confidence to be
     766,489,720 rows (29,893,099,080 bytes).  The estimated time for
     this step is 1 minute and 21 seconds. 
  8) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 3 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan , grouping by field1 (
     TEMP.T1.PRODUCT_SNO ,TEMP.T2.PRODUCT_SNO
     ,TEMP.T3.PRODUCT_SNO ,TEMP.T4.PRODUCT_SNO
     ,TEMP.T1.ACCESS_METHOD_ID).  Aggregate Intermediate Results
     are computed globally, then placed in Spool 9.  The aggregate
     spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool 9 is
     estimated with low confidence to be 574,867,290 rows (
     46,564,250,490 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 6
     minutes and 38 seconds. 
  9) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 9 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan , grouping by field1 (
     TEMP.T1.PRODUCT_SNO ,TEMP.T2.PRODUCT_SNO
     ,TEMP.T3.PRODUCT_SNO ,TEMP.T4.PRODUCT_SNO).  Aggregate
     Intermediate Results are computed globally, then placed in Spool
     11.  The size of Spool 11 is estimated with low confidence to be
     50,625 rows (3,695,625 bytes).  The estimated time for this step
     is 41.87 seconds. 
 10) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 11 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan into Spool 1 (all_amps), which is redistributed
     by the hash code of (TEMP.T1.PRODUCT_SNO,
     TEMP.T2.PRODUCT_SNO, TEMP.T3.PRODUCT_SNO,
     TEMP.T4.PRODUCT_SNO) to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order
     Spool 1 by row hash.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low
     confidence to be 50,625 rows (1,873,125 bytes).  The estimated
     time for this step is 0.04 seconds. 
 11) We do an all-AMPs MERGE into TEMP.TABLE2 from
     Spool 1 (Last Use).  The size is estimated with low confidence to
     be 50,625 rows.  The estimated time for this step is 1 second. 
 12) We spoil the parser's dictionary cache for the table. 
 13) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1.
```

All the required stats are collected.

Comment: I would suggest you ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  In the meantime, study up on `JOIN` syntax so your queries can enter the 21st Century.

Comment: The problem is you ARE joining the same table multiple times. You're also joining to T5 unconditionally.. i.e. a cartesian join. so if T5 has a non-trivial rowcount it's bound to be slow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff    My logic requires me to do such a join. Is there any other way to avoid such join?

Comment: @JeffUK There is no matching condition for T5. What option do i have?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says, we need to know what you are trying to achieve to tell you if there's some other way of achieving it!

Comment: What's the DDL of those tables? And how many AMPs got your system?What's the data in `_TWM_GROUP_COUNT`? You do some strange things, the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` will be 1 all the time and the `MAX` is probably also stupid. Which business question should be solved by this query?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why are you self-joining 5 times?  What is the purpose of this query?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I am not an expert with Teradata, but I did a quick check, and you can use the ANSI JOIN syntax.

So first I rewrote your query so I could understand it:

```
INSERT INTO 
    "TEMP"."TABLE2"
SELECT
    T1."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T2."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T3."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T4."PRODUCT_SNO",
    ((COUNT(DISTINCT T1."ACCESS_METHOD_ID")(FLOAT)) / 
        (MAX(T5.GROUP_NUM(FLOAT))))
FROM
    "TEMP"."TABLE1" T1
    INNER JOIN "TEMP"."TABLE1" T2 ON T2."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T1."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" 
        AND T2."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" > T1."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
    INNER JOIN "TEMP"."TABLE1" T3 ON T3."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T2."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" 
        AND T3."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" > T2."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
    INNER JOIN "TEMP"."TABLE1" T4 ON T4."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" = T3."ACCESS_METHOD_ID" 
        AND T4."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE" > T3."SUBSCRIPTION_DATE"
    CROSS JOIN "TEMP"."_TWM_GROUP_COUNT" T5
GROUP BY 
    T1."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T2."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T3."PRODUCT_SNO",
    T4."PRODUCT_SNO";
```

Note that many of those changes are just a personal preference, but others will "allow your queries to enter the 21st Century" ;P

Now I can read your SQL I can make a number of assumptions on what you are actually trying to achieve here:

- you have some table that has products in it, each product has a serial number, an "access method"(no idea what this is?) and a subscription date;
- you are finding products with the same "access method" and then chaining them together into subscription date order, then you display the serial number of each product in the chain;
- each chain must be exactly 4 products long.  No idea what happens if there are either less than or more than 4 products in a chain (well I can see that if there are less than 4 products in a chain then this will be discarded);
- you also have a metric which turns this logic on its head.  Now you are counting the number of distinct access methods per chain, and dividing this by some number that comes from another table that we know nothing at all about.

That isn't really a lot to go on, but I can see a few places that you could look to optimise:

- you only ever use that _TMW_GROUP_COUNT table for one thing, the MAX(GROUP_NUM).  So you could work that out ahead of the main query then remove the need for this potentially expensive JOIN.  I have no idea how you could do this with Teradata, but in other SQL variants you could stick this into a variable, use a common table expression, use a sub query, etc.  If there are many rows in that table, then there is the potential that the optimiser will run your query x times, then discard x-1 result sets!
- any non-equi join is going to be inefficient, but it doesn't appear as though you can avoid these.  If your table isn't indexed by SUBSCRIPTION_DATE then it might help to pre-sort the data in the table, adding a numeric order number (again in other variants of SQL this would be a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUBSCRIPTION_DATE) type syntax.  Then your date comparison could be a numeric comparison;
- obviously indexes are going to be important here;
- finally, you could split the query into stages, starting with the T1 to T2 join, then using this as the basis for the (T1 to T2) to T3 join, etc.  This might not help, but it's possibly worth a try?

That's probably not a lot of help, but there isn't really enough to go on without some sample data, etc. really...